# Auto navigate WebBrowser in PPT

Tags: browser, powerpoint

In one page of my ppt, I insert a WebBrowser control. I want this WebBrowser navigate to a URL automatically when this page is on the show.
Currently I have to insert a CommandButton and set like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
  WebBrowser1.Navigate "url", 0, 0, 0, 0
End Sub
```

Plz how can I let it be triggered automatically instead click the CommandButton?

Answer (score 1):

This page on Chirag Dalal's site explains the OnSlideShowPageChange event

http://officeone.mvps.org/vba/run_macro_at_slide.html

As implied by the name, it only fires during slide shows.